# installing front end folder in Agora isn't working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, agora.io

i'm trying to install Agora video chat template on my VS code , i've deploy the back end it to Heroku and download the source code from Agora and install it on my npm window , when i run the command `npm start` , it installs only the back end directory and ignore the front end , and this is the error message i got :

```
 ⌂ Main Menu  ▼ install                                                                       ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐                                                                                              │                                                              │√ Node >= 14.0 exists                                                                         │ Description                                                  │√ Cleaned project directories                                                                 │ Installs the codebase onto your local machine                │| Downloading frontend                                                                        │                                                              │√ Downloading backend                                                                         │                                                              │                                                                                              │                                                              │                                                                                              │                                                              │                                                                                              │                                                              │                                                                                              └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\current project\agora-chat-app\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: spawn npx ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\current project\agora-chat-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\current project\agora-chat-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\current project\agora-chat-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\current project\agora-chat-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npx',
  path: 'npx',
  spawnargs: [
    'react-native',
    'init',
    'omarchat2022',
    '--title',
    '"Group video by Omar Allam"',
    '--template',
    'agora-appbuilder-core@2.0.2',
    '--skip-install'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a Node.js error, I'd suggest updating Node.js to the LTS release.